# KeyError 'CONTENT_TYPE' only in dev server

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have the following code that works perfectly fine in my local development environment, but when I use the same on the project dev server I get a `KeyError: 'CONTENT_TYPE'`

views.py:

```
if request.META['CONTENT_TYPE'] == 'text/plain':
    context = {}
    context['All'] = {'total': Theme.objects.all().count(), 'id': 0}

    for t in ThemeCategory.objects.all():
        context[t.categoryName] = {'total': t.theme_set.count(), 'id': t.id}
    context = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(context.items()))
    if request.user.is_anonymous():
        token = "false"
    else:
        token = get_json_web_token(request.user)
```

This is deployed in EC2 server with help of `gunicorn` and only **getting error** by running **through gunicorn** but by running in `localhost` it works.
What could be the issue here?

Any help is appreciated.